# $(\int f_1d\mu)^2+\cdots+(\int f_nd\mu)^2\leq(\int \sqrt{f_1^2+\cdots+f_n^2}d\mu)^2$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X, \mathfrak{B}, \mu)$ be a measurable space, possibly not $\sigma$-finite, and $f_1, \cdots, f_n \colon X\to (-\infty, +\infty)$ be integrable functions on $X$. Does $$(\int f_1d\mu)^2+\cdots+(\int f_nd\mu)^2\leq(\int \sqrt{f_1^2+\cdots+f_n^2}d\mu)^2$$ holds? (Since $\sqrt{f_1^2+\cdots+f_n^2}\leq |f_1|+\cdots+|f_n|$, note that integrand in RHS is integrable.)

My first attempt was to apply the Fubini's theorem and Cauchy-Schwarz to the LHS: 
$\begin{align}(LHS)&=(\int f_1(x)d\mu(x))(\int f_1(y)d\mu(y))+\cdots+(\int f_n(x)d\mu(x))(\int f_n(y)d\mu(y))\\&=\int f_1(x)f_1(y)+\cdots+f_n(x)f_n(y) d(\mu\otimes\mu)(x,y)\\ &\leq\int \sqrt{f_1^2(x)+\cdots+f_n^2(x)}\sqrt{f_1^2(y)+\cdots+f_n^2(y)}d(\mu\otimes\mu)(x,y)\\&=(RHS)\end{align} $

However this approach is valid only if $X$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Note that the inequation is equivalent to the following: If $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is integrable, $$|\int f d\mu|\leq \int|f| d\mu$$

Comment: Jensen's inequality would apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality

Comment: @Oliver Diaz: I finally understood why we need $\sigma$ finite. It is because we replace the measure with an equivalent probability measure. However, we can restrict ourselves with $\sigma$-finite measures when we deal with the integral of a single $L^1$ function, since we can ignore the $0$ set ( and the rest must be $\sigma$-finite).

Comment: @orangeskid: The $\sigma$-finite case is solved already by nessy. Her concern was the non-$\sigma$-finte case, where her using of Fubini's theorem does not apply and certainly Jensen's either. Her insight however gives more ore less the path to follow, i.e.  $\|\int f\|\leq\int\|f\|$ where $\|\;\|$ is Eucliean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It turns out that the aforemetioned inequality holds in very general settings. See solution below

Comment: Quite late to the party, but I just wanted to mention that $\sigma$-finiteness is not needed for the proof in the question. Simply write the integrals as iterated integrals instead of integrals with respect to the product measure and everything follows from elementary properties of integration, no need to invoke Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple of strategies that work in general and make no use of any type of local integrability properties of the underlying measure ($\sigma$-finiteness or not).

---

The simpler solution may be obtained by applying linear functionals to the vector $\int f=\sum^n_{j=1}e_j\int f_j\,d\mu$ where $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Denote by $|\,|_p$ is $p$-norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We use the fact that $(\mathbb{R}^n,|;|_p)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n,|\,|_q)$ are dual to each other when $\tfrac1p+\tfrac1q=1$.

If $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is linear, then $\Lambda x =x\cdot u$ for some unique $u\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus

\begin{aligned}
\Lambda \Big(\int f\Big) &= u\cdot\Big(\int f\Big)=\sum^n_{j=1}u_j\int f_j\,d\mu =\int u\cdot f\,d\mu
\end{aligned}
and so, by Hölder's inequality (in $\mathbb{R}^n$)
\begin{aligned}
\left|\Lambda \Big(\int f\Big)\right|&=\Big|\int u\cdot f\,d\mu\Big|\leq\int|u\cdot f|\,d\mu\\
&\leq\int\|u\|_q\|f\|_p\,d\mu=\|u\|_q\int\|f\|_p\,d\mu
\end{aligned}
The result than follows by taking $\sup$ over all linear functionals $\Lambda$ with functional norm $\|\Lambda\|:=\sup_{\|x\|_p=1}|\Lambda x|\leq1$, or equivalently, by taking $\sup$ over all vectors $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|u\|_q=1$.  Thus

$$\left\|\int f\right\|_p \leq \int\|f\|_p\,d\mu$$

---

The next alternative, can be seen as an overj=kill, but the ideas carry over  functions with values in Banach spaces.
Consider the space $L$ of functions  $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ which are integrable in each component and define $\|f\|^*=\int|f|_2\,d\mu$, where $|\;|_2$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is defines a norm on $L$ since  $\|f\|^*\leq\sum^n_{k=1}\int|f|_j\,d\mu<\infty$. Also,
$$
\int||f|_2-|g|_2|\,d\mu\leq\int|f-g|_2\,d\mu=\|f-g\|^*
$$

Consider $\mathcal{E}$ the collection of (integrable) simple functions on $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$
and define
$$\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathcal{E}=\{\sum^m_{k=1}u_k\phi_k: u_k\in\mathbb{R}^n, \phi_k\in\mathcal{E}, m\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

This space will play the role of elementary functions in the construction of the real valued integral. It is easy to check that $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathcal{E}$ is dense in $(L,\|\;\|^*)$; furthermore,  any function in $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathcal{E}$ can be expressed as
$$
\Phi=\sum^{M}_{j=1}v_j\mathbb{1}_{A_j}
$$
where $v_j\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A_j\in\mathscr{B}$, $\mu(A_j)<\infty$, and $M\in\mathbb{N}$.
Consider now the elementary integral
$$\int\Big(\sum^m_{k=1}u_k\phi_k\Big):=\sum^m_{j=1}u_k\int\phi_k\,d\mu$$

Since $\Phi=\sum_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}u\mathbb{1}_{\{\Phi=u\}}$ (notice that the sum over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is actually finite),
$$
\int\Phi =\sum^m_{j=1}u_j\mu(A_j)=\sum_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}u\int\mathbb{1}_{\{\Phi=u\}}\,d\mu\tag{1}\label{one}
$$

which means that the elementary integral extended to $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathcal{E}$ does not depend on any particular representation of $\Phi$. Now
$$
\Big|\int\Phi\Big|_2\leq\sum_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}|u|_2\int\mathbb{1}_{\{\Phi=u\}}\,d\mu=\int\Big(\sum_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}|u|_2\mathbb{1}_{\{\Phi=u\}}\Big)\,d\mu=\int|\Phi|_2\,d\mu=\|\Phi\|^*\tag{2}\label{two}
$$
$\eqref{two}$ is the inequality you are looking for but only for functions in $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathcal{E}$. For all functions in $L$ one can use some density arguments.

---

**Comments:**

1. Notice that  $|\;|_2$ can be replaced by $|\;|_p$ ($p\geq1$).
2. Your problem is an example of an integral defined on vector--valued functions.
3. The arguments used, with some technical additions (Daniell integration, and measurability issues) can be used to construct Bochner's integral where  $\mathbb{R}^n$ is replaced by a Banach space.

Comment: I like the last proof; it seems to work for a general (semi)norm $\|\cdot \|$. By Hahn-Banach, given any $v (= \int_X f)$ there exists a functional of norm $1$, call it $L$, so that $\|v\| = L(v)$.  Then apply your method and get $\|v\| \le \|L \| \cdot \int_X \|f\|$. This should be the "canonical" proof.  Nice, thank you.

Comment: The first proof is more or less how one constructs Bochner’s integral through the Daniell procedure. the later is close to how one construct Bochner integral through the Dunford  integral.

Comment: I took a look at the definition of Pettis integral. The second solution should also work for this integral.

Comment: Yes, the Pettis integral. I confuse him with Dunford, as in the Dunford-Pettis theorem. Any way, that type of integral is useful even when functions take values on more abstract linear spaces (at least locally convex). The advantage of Bochner+Daniell is that one can derive a natural notion of measurability (Caratheodory's cut idea does not work here).

Answer (score 1):

First, assume that $(X,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$ finite space. Then there exists a probability measure $\nu$ on $X$ that is equivalent to $\mu$, that is 
$$\mu =  \rho \cdot \nu $$ where $\rho>0$ is a measurable function, $\rho>0$. We have for every $f\in L^1(X, \mu)$
$$\int_X f d\mu = \int_X f \, d\, \rho \nu = \int_X \rho f\, d \nu$$

Now, let $\phi$ be a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is also positively homogeneous ( a [sublinear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function)). Then we have 
$$\int_X \phi( f) d \mu= \int_X \rho \phi(f) d\nu = \int_X \phi(\rho f) d\nu \ge \phi(\int_X \rho f d\nu ) = \phi( \int_X f d\mu)$$

The inequality above is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),  for the convex functions $\phi$ and the function $L^1$ $\rho f$ on the probability space $(X,\nu)$.

We can reduce to the case $X$ $\sigma$-finite as follows: Consider $X' = \{x\in X | f(x) \ne 0\}$. Since $f$ is $L^1$, all the subsets 
$\{x |\  |f(x)|\ge 1/n\}$ are have finite measure. Hence $X'$ is $\sigma$-finite. We can reduce all our integrals to integrals over $X'$.

Now, how to find the  probability measure $\nu$ equivalent to $\mu$. Let $X= \sqcup_n X_n$ where $\mu(X_n) <\infty$.  Now, find  $\eta>0$  such that $\int_X \eta\, d\mu = 1$, for instance $$\eta=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{\chi(X_n)}{\mu(X_n)} $$ Put $\nu = \eta \cdot \mu$.

$\bf{Added:}$ I think the natural solution is the second one of @Oliver Diaz, let's restate it in general terms.

Consider $\|\cdot \|$ a seminorm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or, more generaly, a sublinear function). We want to show the inequality
$$\| \int_X f d\mu \| \le \int_X \|f\| d \mu$$

Denote by $v \colon =  \int_X f d\mu$.  By [Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem), there exists a linear functional $L\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $L(v) = \|v\|$, and $L(w)\le \|w\|$ for all $\|w\|\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We get
$$\|\int_X f d\mu \| = L(\int_X f d\mu)=\int_X L(f) d\mu \le \int_X \|f\| d\mu$$

Comment: The problem requires a "vector" version of Jensen's inequality (for the $\sigma$--finite case). The function here is an $\mathbb{R}^n$--valued integrable function. A proof of a version for Jensen's on this setting though not difficult, it does require  more than the standard real line version.