# Integral inequalities with total variation measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I know and I can prove that, given $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $L^1_{|\mu|}(\Omega)$, then
$$\left|\int_{\Omega}f\,d\mu\right|\leq \int_{\Omega}|f|d|\mu|$$
where $|\mu|$ is the total variation measure of $\mu$. But the same holds even if $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is a vector-valued Radon measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\int_{\Omega} f\,d\mu=(\int_\Omega fd\mu_1,...,\int_\Omega f d\mu_d)$. How can I prove it?

Comment: ?? What are $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots$? Shouldn't it be $(\int_\Omega f_1\,d\mu, \int_\Omega f_2\,d\mu, \dots)$?

Comment: $\mu$ is a vector Radon measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$ while $f$ is not vector-valued.

Comment: You said "$f:\Omega \to \Bbb R^d$". How is that "not vector-valued"?

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. I'll fix it

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696228/121671